# How to call data with variables that we want

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a system which provide a report generator, now my problem is i dont know how to call data with the variables that i want. For example I only want the data from January // 2014 // from the account department and so on. Now, i don't know what code to show but below is the menu where user select their variables

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showForm() {
        var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
        if (selopt == "Tenaga Nasional Berhad") {
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (selopt == "Telekom Malaysia") {
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (selopt == 0) {
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="contact_form">                   
  <h4>Pilih Ketetapan Laporan</h4>                                                                                                                                                                      
  <form method="post" name="pilih_kategori_daftar">       
    <label for="daerah">Daerah:</label>

    <select class="required input_field" name="daerah" id="daerah" required/>                              
      <option value="">--Pilih Daerah--</option>
      <option value="Kuantan">Kuantan</option>
      <option value="Maran">Maran</option>
      <option value="Bentong">Bentong</option>
      <option value="Raub">Lipis</option>
      <option value="Jerantut">Jerantut</option>
      <option value="Cameron Highlands">Cameron Highlands</option>
      <option value="P.Tenggara">Pahang Tenggara</option>
      <option value="Pekan">Pekan</option>
      <option value="Rompin">Rompin</option>
      <option value="Temerloh">Temerloh</option>
      <option value="Bera">Bera</option>
      <option value="Ibu Pejabat">Ibu Pejabat</option>
    </select> 
    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

    <label for="bulan_bill">Bulan</label> 
    <select class="required bill_caj" name="bulan_bill" id="bulan_bill" width="300px" required/>
      <option value="">--Pilih Bulan--</option>
      <option value="Januari">Januari</option>
      <option value="Februari">Februari</option>
      <option value="Mac">Mac</option>
      <option value="April">April</option>
      <option value="Mei">Mei</option>
      <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
      <option value="Julai">Julai</option>
      <option value="Ogos">Ogos</option>
      <option value="September">September</option>
      <option value="Oktober">Oktober</option>
      <option value="November">November</option>
      <option value="Disember">Disember</option>
    </select>
    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

    <label for="tahun_bill">Tahun</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" id="tahun_bill" name="tahun_bill" class="required year_field" placeholder="Tahun" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" required/>
    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

    <label for="kategori_akaun">Kategori</label>
    <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()" class="input_field" required>
      <option value="0">--Pilih Kategori--</option>
      <option value="Tenaga Nasional Berhad">Akaun TNB</option>
      <option value="Telekom Malaysia">Akaun TM</option>
    </select>
    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

    <div id="f1" style="display:none">
      <form name="akaun_tnb">
        <label for="jenis">Jenis Akaun</label>
        <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()"class="input_field">
          <option value="0">--Pilih Jenis Akaun--</option>
          <option value="Rumah Pam">Rumah Pam</option>
          <option value="Loji Air">Loji Air</option>
          <option value="Stor">Stor</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="f2" style="display:none">
      <form name="akaun_tm">
        <label for="jenis">Jenis Akaun</label>
        <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()"class="input_field">
        <option value="0">--Pilih Jenis Akaun--</option>
        <option value="Telefon">Telefon</option>
        <option value="Telefon/Streamyx">Telefon/Streamyx</option>
        <option value="Streamyx">Streamyx</option>
        <option value="SMS Blast">SMS Blast</option>
        <option value="TM NET">TM NET</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>                      
  </form>                   
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the code to submit form for father processing, extract data from database - be more specific..

Comment: Why are you using PHP, MYSQL, SQL phpMyAdmin tags? these are not relevant tags!

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "call data with the variables that I want"; as-in retrieve data from a backend database/web service based on the inputs from the form?

Comment: i want the code which will retrieve/show the data from the database with variables that user choose in this menu @SergePavloff

Comment: the input from the form above is based on the data that are in the tables...thus the user will select which data to be shown...maybe kind a like sorting, not sure @isim

Comment: So do you have you database tables set up? @itsfawwaz

Comment: set up as in ?  @SergePavloff

Comment: This is not a place where you get people to create custom applications for free:) What you need is to learn how to search for the right topics, where you can get relevant information to build your app

Comment: well you've stated phpmyadmin...

Comment: yeah i know, i'm hoping that someone can somehow give some info on how to do it or what to search/learn :) @SergePavloff

Comment: already got that part right mate :) just don't know how extract data from the tables using the selection that user make, though im  not sure what's that called @SergePavloff

Answer (score 0):

search in google:

1, How to create mysqli database, tables, columns.

2, PHP, how to connect, extract, insert data from mysqli using php,

3. How to echo mysqli data into html,

4. how to submit form to php and insert data to mysqli,

5. Learn to use AJAX & JSON...this you may leave for few months:)

Comment: already got that part right mate :) just don't know how extract data from the tables using the selection that user make, though im not sure what's that called

Comment: some selects don't have a name, add the names and then call in your php processing code: `code` if(!empty($_POST['selectName'])){mysqli query}